# RequireJS shim config in webpack

Tags: requirejs, webpack

I want to port my requirejs web application to webpack module bundler. The app use several non AMD libraries (such jquery and bootstrap). RequireJS maintains such libraries via shim configuration. How I can declare dependincies for non AMD libraries in webpack?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your current RequireJS configuration? That way we can provide a better idea of what it would look like in Webpack. Generally put you will probably want to look into [resolve.alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) to deal with these.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of doing the same. It's practically as you would any AMD module. To use stringified templates put into AngularJS' `$templateCache` as an example:

Templates are generated in non-AMD format wrapped in an IIFE, pushed into a `.tmp` dir, then requested as per any module:

```js
define([
  './module',
  'templates/ubCampaignEditor'
]
```

As to keep definitions clean, I've created a `resolve.alias` named `templates`, in the Webpack config:

```js
resolve: {
  alias: {
    templates: path.join(__dirname, '.tmp/templates')
  }
}
```